# Referral with regex for firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, regex, http-referrer

I am looking for a firefox referral plugin. I would like to be able to forge the referral name based on the pagename without extension. Such as

```
 http://site.com/page/abc.ANYTHING
```

I need to set the referral as

```
 http://site.com/view/blah-abc-more.ext
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to get the [Modify HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967). Now this will not modify the referer dynamically based on the site domain. So you now have these options:

1. Ask for this feature
2. Modify the existing exentension
3. OR, compeletly different, find a proxy that offers this feature, run it locally, point firefox to it, and viola, your referer has changed on your outbound call to the intended server.
4. Write such a proxy, would be pretty simple for a programmer the least bit familiar with http.

Comment: I ended up modifying one. it was a PITA